# Stripe - getting payment fee upfront

Tags: payment-gateway, stripe-payments

I am currently integrating my platform with Stripe (connect marketplace). In this platform the Stripe payment fees are uplifted by the users. The marketplace will be global so it is not restricted to any one country so the cards will be from everywhere (EU and non-EU).

I can't see any API that gives me the payment fee upfront (only after the charge has been made). Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

No, application fees are collected out of payments you collect from customers for your connected accounts, for example with [destination charges](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges#application-fee).

If you want to collect fees from your providers outside of a customer payment, you need to either collect payment from them as customers or [debit their connected account balance](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-debits) (though this is not always available or appropriate).